# Need to print the values which have non zero values

Tags: shell, awk

Esteemed Fellows,

I have file which have the below data format, where first is host-name and second is time i just need to print the host-names which will have non zero values in second field(00:00).

I'm looking for a way around any help will be helpful.

```
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:02)
[vmlnl339] (00:04)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:01)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:07)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)
[vmlnl339] (00:00)



[vmlnl073] (1+07:08)
[vmlnl073] (00:00)
[vmlnl073] (00:04)
[vmlnl073] (00:00)
[vmlnl073] (00:47)
[vmlnl073] (00:00)
[vmlnl073] (00:00)
[vmlnl073] (00:00)
[vmlnl073] (00:00)
[vmlnl073] in
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '$2 != "(00:00)"' file
```

or even `grep`:

```
grep -v '(00:00)'
```

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`

```
sed '/(00:00)$/d' file
```

or similarly with `awk`

```
awk '!/\(00:00\)$/' file
```

Comment: not working? not filtering zeros or doesn't print anything?

Comment: not printing anything.. `awk:                          ^ backslash not last character on line`

Answer (score 1):

Use awk:

```
awk '!($0 ~ "00:00")' sample.csv
```

Use sed:

```
sed -n  '/00:00/!p' sample.csv
```